# I am not able to install pyaudio library on windows 11

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
  C:\Users\mudit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
```

when I am trying to install pyaudio it gives me a error

Comment: Pyaudio depends on the  portaudio library. On linux `sudo apt install portaudio19-dev` on windows you need to install portaudio too. Perhaps you can find it in the pyaudio docs how and where to install portaudio

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. To find the linked duplicate, all I had to do was put `pyaudio portaudio.h` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pyaudio+portaudio.h). It was the first result for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually pyaudio cant be installed now as python  has ended its support
but if you need py audio donwload from here[enter link description here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

choose the correct version of pyaudio or simply watch this video on youtube
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKymlea8sYM)